# JSF and jquery vs Primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I work on JSF2.0 along with jquery. And I get to use primefaces now. My doubt is, the way of script usage and syntaxes in primefaces is completely different from general JSF, Jquery way of using. I am very much confused that which one I have to use- whether primefaces scripting approach or Primefaces element with jquery approach. Is it possible to eleminate primefaces way of javascript usage and use jquery for primeface elements as well (like we do JSF/Jquery combo). Please clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces uses jQuery and jQuery UI. In my experience it's the best to just use the version prime faces delivers to build your own scripts, which is usually possible without problems.

Some Primeface elements allow you to interact with themselves over a Client Side API (see the documentation for more about it). Unfortunately this is not true for all elements.

Comment: Thanks. For example: generally in JSF, if we want to open a dialog box, we write : a.) **onclick="jQuery('#carDialog).dialog('open')"**. But in primefaces, it will be like: b.) **oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()"**. If I want to use primefaces in a jsf/jquery page, I get confused which one of the above to use (a or b)and what if we avoid using Prime faces approach(b). Please clarify

Comment: Could you please answer my above question. Thanks.

Comment: hmmm impatient... ;-)? PF components are based on jquery-ui framework, not necessarlily the jquery-ui components. So they have or can have a different api. If you start combining all different extrernal jquery-ui components, you will get different apis as well. So that part of the question is imo a non-issue. Use the PF api (and onclick vs oncomplete is a whole different story...)

If you don't want to use PF, that is an option. You can start wrapping jquery-ui components in custom or composite components and implement all ajax stuff etc yourself... That choice is completely up to you

Comment: What Kukeltje said. I recommend that you use the primefaces  components as long as you can. I would only switch to jquery if you need to.

Comment: @Kukeltje. Hi, So, in the above context, you mean to say that its better to use jquery for jsf elements and PF for Primefaces elements if we want to use both in a page? Thanks.

Comment: @user2246638: You have to be waaay more specific... jquery by itself does NOTHING, even jquery-ui has a very select set of components. And it is not 'better' to use PF (the api?) for PrimeFaces, it is a requirement. And you can't use that api for the other non PF jquery-ui based components.

Comment: @Kukeltje Hi, Can you please tell me atleast one element on which jquery ui doesnt work. Thanks alot.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no clue on what you mean by that question…

Comment: @Kukeltje Hi, As you mentioned **even jquery-ui has a very select set of components** in the above comment, Can you please give an example for that. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there is the http://www.jqueryui.com site with 'just' these
Widgets: Accordion, Autocomplete, Button, Datepicker, Dialog, Menu, Progressbar, Selectmenu, Slider, Spinner, Tabs, Tooltip. All non-jsf-ified etc. And yes, there are a zilion additional widgets out there, but try to combine those all and make them all jsf-aware... Goodluck. PF started out that way, but came to the conclusion that all these widgets were not designed to be used in jsf in a good way, so they created their own widgets

Comment: Mate I think you need to figure out what the difference between JSF/Jquery and PrimeFaces is, your thing is 'in JSF we do this' and literally it has nothing to do with JSF that piece of code is JQuery and you can use that in any environment, even vanilla html. PrimeFaces just give syou cooler widgets and stylings with JSF interaction. Your JQuery literally does nothing but what's on the DOM.